# Having problems with the HTML 5 Ruby Tag

Tags: html

I am trying to use the [HTML 5 Ruby Tag](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-ruby-element) to display some Japanese text.

I tried two examples.

The first one:

```html
<p>
  <ruby>
      <rb lang="ja">斎</rb><rp>(</rp><rt lang="ja">さい</rt><rp>)</rp>
      <rb lang="ja">藤</rb><rp>(</rp><rt lang="ja">とう</rt><rp>)</rp>
      <rb lang="ja">信</rb><rp>(</rp><rt lang="ja">のぶ</rt><rp>)</rp>
      <rb lang="ja">男</rb><rp>(</rp><rt lang="ja">お</rt><rp>)</rp>
      <rtc>
       <rt rbspan="4" lang="en">W3C Associate Chairman</rt>
      </rtc>
     </ruby>
</p>
```

It shows ruby text without any problems.

[Example 1 - correct](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Sri1.jpg)

However, I tried the other one.

```html
<p>
  <ruby>
      <rbc>
       <rb lang="ja">斎</rb>
       <rb lang="ja">藤</rb>
       <rb lang="ja">信</rb>
       <rb lang="ja">男</rb>
      </rbc>
      <rtc>
       <rp>(</rp><rt lang="ja">さい</rt><rp>)</rp>
       <rp>(</rp><rt lang="ja">とう</rt><rp>)</rp>
       <rp>(</rp><rt lang="ja">のぶ</rt><rp>)</rp>
       <rp>(</rp><rt lang="ja">お</rt><rp>)</rp>
      </rtc>
      <rtc>
       <rt rbspan="4" lang="en">W3C Associate Chairman</rt>
      </rtc>
     </ruby>
</p>
```

It does not shows ruby text like below:

[Example 2 - problem(2)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kBg77.png)

What is the problem with the second one?

I'm testing on iPad Pro (iOS 10.3.3)

Comment: Maybe this is a CSS problem? This is HTML, no?

Comment: I did not add any tags about CSS code, such as style or link tags. Examples are shown by browser default. It is a problem? Which CSS code should I add?

Comment: This won't look like what you're asking for without CSS. In fact, I'm not even sure how Ruby factors in here since this looks like 100% HTML, no styling, no Ruby, no anything else.

Comment: Well, you mean I should apply CSS explicitly? I'd like to know what I should add.

Comment: This question is frustratingly vague. I have no idea how the first one shows up like it does, nor why the second one doesn't. This is a **CSS styling problem** and unless you've written that style, can find out what styles are in play, or otherwise dig up the source for that, this is not something we can help with. If you need mentoring or coaching try services like [Codementor](https://www.codementor.io), [Savvy](https://www.savvy.is), [Hackhands](https://hackhands.com), or [airpair](https://www.airpair.com).

Comment: I modified my question and pasted full source code.

Comment: @tadman question is about [this](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_ruby.asp), not ruby the programming language.

Comment: @LucianoJeong this is a pretty obscure HTML tag (at least to European and American developers), so I'm not sure how to help you. I also edited your question and title because `Ruby` is also the name of a popular programming language which is confusing (not your fault). No CSS *should* be required, I'm not sure why your second example is failing.